# Unable to hit webservice on tomcat getting 500 error

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

Please help me here:-
project name:- RESTFULWebService

java class:-

```
package com.packages.restful;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/two")
public class SimpleRESTFULService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String simpleMessage() {

        return "<p>This is a simple RESTFUL WebService</p>";

    }
}
```

web.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RESTFULWebService</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>RESTFULWebService</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/one/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

i placed Jersey 1.18 lib, ext all jars in my lib folder
URL i am using :-
http://localhost:8080/RESTFULWebService/one/two
but i am getting error:-
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:1


root cause

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
```

**please help me here, i searched entire google, but though i worte everything correctly why i am not getting output?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of param `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` must the Java package where you have the resources (classes annotated with `@Path`).

So, you need to change this:

```xml
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>RESTFULWebService</param-value>
</init-param>
```

By:

```xml
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.packages.restful</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Nice, Solved my problem, really thanks,But i tried this before then it doesnt work for me, any how thanks!!